# What are the Limitations of Deploying to Meteor.com?

Tags: meteor

What are the limitations of deploying my application to meteor.com (aka, what is the catch?) I assume there must be something about it that would keep me from running something like Facebook or StackOverflow off of it.

Examples of what the limitations might be:

- I'm limited to X concurrent users.
- I'm limited to X requests of type Y per time period Z.
- My database is limited to X GB.

I found this thread from 2012 that suggests there are no limitations:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/HqDvR1sF3-4/YEqrXpDqVGcJ

Is the only limitation still just that I have no guarantee of service and what they have is what I get? If that's the case, what do they have powering the service, and what kind of load is it under?

Are there any legal things I should keep in mind while doing this, IE, is Meteor copyleft or am I forbidden from making money via whatever I host there (ads or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor free hosting is now dead as per this announcement https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-com-free-hosting-ends-march-25-2016/19308

Now they recommend galaxy for hosting.

If looking for free then heroku is recommended with mongolabs for mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely only for testing and prototyping. Consider this screen when a user visits a meteor.com hosted app that hasn't been loaded in a while.

[image]

Comment: Good point. Still, what if I had a constant stream of people visiting my website (as I imagine is the case for most popular websites)? The site wouldn't ever get unloaded, so nobody would ever end up seeing this.

Comment: A steady stream of visitors is even more reason to move to a production-level server. As a user, I could see myself becoming frustrated quickly if every page load takes too long due to demand. A good prod sever provides niceties like scaling, backups, and access to quality admin tools as well. You could certainly start with hosting your site on meteor and see what kind of feedback you get and then see if you need to scale up.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying) says:

> We provide this as a free service so you can try Meteor.

So you should only deploy apps to meteor.com that you want to test. They're working on an infrastructure called [Galaxy](https://trello.com/c/FMdB7GAu/78-galaxy-managed-production-quality-meteor-deploy) that you'll be able to use to deploy your apps for real, but it will cost money.

Comment: Yeah, but a statement in the docs doesn't keep you from abusing it.

Comment: Are you asking if you can abuse it without getting caught? They offer the test service for free, be grateful, not greedy.

Comment: I'm asking for what "abusing it" would consist of. Obviously if my website doesn't require much resources I could just have it be my production version and nobody would care. Alternatively, maybe my website is so heavy that just testing it causes problems for their test service. So saying it has to be for test purposes seems like a poor definition to go with. I'd like to know some actual limitations. I think I heard something about the website needing to finish launching within 4 minutes...

Comment: IMHO, you should never use it for production, nor benchmarking, even if your app is tiny. If you want to test your app, just deploy it and see what happens (that's testing). I don't think the exact numbers you give as example exist (I've never read anything like that, and I've been following Meteor over the last 2 years), but if you want further guidelines I guess you have to ask the MDG directly.

Comment: My guess is that it'll become a lot clearer once Galaxy is done. They'll put hard numbers down for what can be on their test services vs what can be done on Galaxy, much as Parse.com clearly gives you the rules for what you can do with their service for free vs what they'll charge you for.